# How to calculate the computational complexity of machine learning algorithms

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have used five machine learning algorithms, including the artificial neural network (ANN), random forest, CatBoost, SVM, and K-nearest neighbors (KNN) for a multiclass classification. How can I compute the computational complexity of these models?

I have also utilized the Power-Law Committee Machine (PLCM) to combine the outputs the five machine learning algorithms as the sixth method. I also need to calculate the computational complexity of this method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Bayesian Informative Criterion (BIC) to compute the simplicity of the models. BIC depends on the variance of the predictions by each model. If BIC is low, the simplicity is high.